# SetOnClickListener for Button within RecyclerView to access viewmodel and perform action on room database

Tags: button, android-recyclerview, android-room, viewmodel, onclicklistener

I would like to add a "delete" button in a RecyclerView showing a list of "Users" present in a Room Database. The button should permit to delete the single user when clicking on the button. I have tried to insert a function in Myviewholder, but when I call it in OnBindViewHolder the error concerns the initialization of the mUserViewModel. Do you have any suggestion on it?
This is the adapter:

```
class ListAdapterUser: RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapterUser.MyViewHolder>() {

    private var UserList = emptyList<User>()
    private lateinit var mUserViewModel: UserViewModel


    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        val button = itemView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.deleteoption)

        fun deleteitem(item: User, viewModel: UserViewModel){
            button.setOnClickListener{
                viewModel.deleteUser(item)
        }}
    }


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        return MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.custom_rowUser, parent, false))
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return UserList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = UserList[position]
        holder.itemView.textview_valueUser.text = currentItem.Uservalue.toString()

        holder.deleteitem(currentItem, mUserViewModel)

    }

    fun setUserData(User: List<User>){
        this.UserList = User
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I am not familiar with Kotlin, but in Java the `SetOnClickListener` is set in the `onBindViewHolder method`. Like `holder.button.setOnClickListener`. Try that

Answer (score 0):

Solved obtaining the viewmodel initialized in the fragment passing it with setUserData function. Here the final code:

```
class ListAdapterUser: RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapterUser.MyViewHolder>() {

private var UserList = emptyList<User>()
private lateinit var mUserViewModel: UserViewModel


class MyViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    val button = itemView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.deleteoption)

    fun deleteitem(item: User, viewModel: UserViewModel){
        button.setOnClickListener{
            viewModel.deleteUser(item)
    }}
}


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
    return MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.custom_rowUser, parent, false))
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return UserList.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val currentItem = UserList[position]
    holder.itemView.textview_valueUser.text = currentItem.Uservalue.toString()

    holder.deleteitem(currentItem, mUserViewModel)

}

fun setUserData(User: List<User>, viewModel: UserViewModel)){
    this.UserList = User
    this.mUserViewModel = viewModel
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}}
```